# ORA-00054 Resource busy when dropping table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00054

Can somebody explain this error?

> ORA-00054: Resource busy and aquire with NOWAIT specified

This error came in a `DROP TABLE`.  Because of it, procedures and packages are not getting compiled.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: actually in my procedure i have used one table which is getting deleted everytime the procedure i execute..so wat has hapn is when i was testing my procedure it was executing endless..so i tried to debug,,and found that line which is deleteing from that table is taking time...so i hav tried to drop that table..then this error came...ORA-00054 Resource busy and aquire with NOWAIT specified

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ORA-00054` means some other session has a lock on a database object which prevents our action from completely successfully.

Your scenario as you present it is a trifle confused, but basically somebody has a lock on the table - probably they are xecuting some DML against it - and you won't be able to drop it until they release that lock (i.e. commit or rollback).

Having said all which I'm not sure why you'd want to drop a table to fix a PL/SQL compilation problem.  You should revise your question to give us a clearer picture of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

you may have a query or a job running against the table. your objects cannot be recompiled or dropped until that long running queries/jobs are finished. Alternatively, you can kill any sessions except yours and then proceed with the compilation.

Comment: @Bhuran..How can i kill all sesiion except current running one..can you please elaborate on that.. Thanks

Comment: if you use TOAD or PL/SQL Developer, then it is easy. you can view the current sessions and their related information like which OS user is logged in, which terminal the session was issued from.

Comment: if you use TOAD or PL/SQL Developer, then it is easy. you can view the current sessions and their related information like which OS user is logged in, which terminal the session was issued from etc. if you are using SQL promot, you can query the v$session to view this information.  however you need to kill each session individually by getting the session id, and issuing the command: SQL> Alter system kill session 'sid,serial#';
you must have necessary rights to view (or kill) sessions.